# Sql - WHERE clause with IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I just tried some example about SELECT ... IN query on w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in

So, first I tried a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 'Paris' IN (City);
```

It returns all row in tables which has city is Paris. But then, when I try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 'Paris' or 1=1 or 'abc' IN (City);
```

It returns everything in the table. I am a bit confused about what happens here, could anyone please explain to me what going on here?

For me, I guess that when the WHERE clause evaluate the expression '1=1' to true, it will ignore the rest of the query and return everything in the table. But it must have another OR expression after '1=1' expression, if I only use:

SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 'Paris' or 1=1 IN (City);

It will cause error! It must have another or expression after '1=1' expression.

Updated: I am using mysql! This is an sql injection that I tried to get all data from a table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 'Paris' or 1=1 or 'abc' IN (City); does not work in SQL Server. Are you using MySQL?

Comment: @Lali, I am using mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE CITY IN ('Paris','Rome','London')
```

is an abbreviated form of

```
WHERE ( CITY = 'Paris' OR CITY = 'Rome' OR CITY = 'London' )
```

In your example

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE ('Paris' or 1) = 1   --<< 1 does = 1 so all rows are returned
   or ('abc' IN (City) )
;
```

Comment: That's a reasonable and nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the WHERE X in Y to select multiple values:

SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City IN ('Paris', 'abc')

Comment: I knew about how it works! Actually, I am trying to perform some sql injection, and got this injection to work. But I just not very sure about this behavior.